# Horn clause on cnf

Tags: reference-request, proof-complexity, resolution

Recall that a CNF formula is Horn if each clause contains at most one positive literal.

Is it possible any unsatisfiable Horn CNF formula has a polynomial-size treelike Resolution refutation? Is there any proof exists in any paper?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, any unsatisfiable Horn CNF has a tree-like resolution refutation with a linear number of clauses.

Consider the standard poly-time Horn-SAT algorithm, which works as follows. First, set all variables to false. Repeat: pick an unsatisfied clause; if it's negative, answer UNSATISFIABLE; otherwise, set its positive literal to true. If all clauses are satisfied, answer SATISFIABLE.

Assume the input formula is unsatisfiable. If you look at the order in which the algorithm sets variables to true, as well as the offending clauses that make it so, you obtain a list of pairwise distinct variables
$$x_0,\dots,x_{t-1}$$
and input clauses
$$C_0,\dots,C_t$$
such that
$$C_i\subseteq\{\neg x_j:j<i\}\cup\{x_i\},\qquad i<t,$$
and
$$C_t\subseteq\{\neg x_j:j<t\}.$$
Construct a tree-like resolution refutation as follows: resolve $D_t:=C_t$ and $C_{t-1}$ over the $x_{t-1}$ variable, obtaining $D_{t-1}$; resolve $D_{t-1}$ and $C_{t-2}$ over $x_{t-2}$ to get $D_{t-2}$; etc., in the last step resolving $D_1$ and $C_0$ over $x_0$ to get $D_0$. By reverse induction on $i\le t$, we see that
$$D_i\subseteq\{\neg x_j:j<i\}.$$
In particular, $D_0$ is the empty clause.

Thus, you obtain a refutation of the input formula $\phi$ whose number of clauses is at most twice the number of distinct variables positively occuring in $\phi$, and whose total size is thus at most quadratic in the size of $\phi$.

Comment: (1) Obviously I have no idea what you may have studied. This is the standard HornSAT algorithm that you can find described in many places, see e.g. https://tryalgo.org/en/satisfiability/2016/12/04/horn-sat/ or https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horn-satisfiability (the latter presents it differently so that the clauses are restricted in the process instead of just maintaining the assignment, but the underlying algorithm is the same). (2) It may easily happen that $D_{i+1}$ does not actually contain $\neg x_i$. This does not matter. If one or both of the principal literals of an instance of the ...

Comment: ... resolution rule are missing, this resolution inference degenerates to an instance of weakening, which can be skipped.